# getting error with hadoop maven build in window 8 platform

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, window

I'm getting below exception when trying to maven build with hadoop 2.6.0 in window 8.1 platform . Please advice .

I'm using maven command "mvn -e package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar" as suggested in "http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows"

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (pre-dist) on project hadoop-project-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="sh">... @ 41:115 in C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (pre-dist) on project hadoop-project-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): Create
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="sh">... @ 41:115 in C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="sh">... @ 41:115 in C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml:41: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:675)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\JAVA\hadoopsource\hadoop-2.6.0-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 40 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-project-dist
```

Comment: it is bit urgent ,  can any one please suggest on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue got resolved after downloading below software and adding respective entry in path environment variable . thank you !!

```
Protocol Buffers 2.5.0
Cygwin
```